# vue ref property not able to infer type correctly

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Want to add an extra property to composeable method but its throwing error `property 'isActive' does not exist on type '{ id: string; text: string; }'`

here is the code

```
import { ref, type Ref } from 'vue';

type ActiveItemType = {
  text: string;
  isActive?: boolean;
};

export const useActiveItems = <T extends ActiveItemType>(data: T[]) => {
  let active = '';

  function activeMapper(d: T) {
    return {
      ...d,
      isActive: d.text === active,
    };
  }
  const itemsData = data.map(activeMapper);

  const items = ref(itemsData) as Ref<T[]>;

  function onSetActive(text: string) {
    active = text;
    items.value = items.value.map(activeMapper);
  }

  // initial set first one
  if (items.value[0]) {
    items.value[0].isActive = true;
  }

  return {
    items,
    onSetActive,
  };
};

const { items } = useActiveItems([
  {
    id: '1',
    text: 't1'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    text: 't2'
  },
]);

if (items.value[0]) {
  items.value[0].isActive; // ERROR
}
```

the [ts-playground-link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzlApgMwDRxgTzCuAJXTgF840oIQ4ByANwFcVaBuAWACgvd84BBAMYxg9FAEkYKEABU8BALyIucbCgAeMAFxwAzjCjAAdgHMOnVcF1CRYgPw6ARhAgAbFAEMj50ua4bIWDhBCCN9OEZdFBtRCSkQXTglAB4ZOA0pIwATRJixSWk5fAA%20AAosjxgPHRkAbQBdAEok4uULOHd4D2FYpLo2LhUKRiMe0Lhu2xQAWQ8wfChymuaEIdVUGEYoIzbVPbgAOiOsjDW9qzyUHSyDqU0khSVJ2NP21V8h0iGQsPhgeN0ABFKh4%20hUqgcQHNSs8xLN5igoI0-O0fuF-tJEkpUGhShiEsCqs0PIliGhUg1iijVGgRmMdqEAMooGCXUp3bR6AzGEwrM6wxRqTTmfb43QHegeVzMPpiiVS5iQ6EC%20ELZGfQbtAD0Wrgxn%20wClehZFGAUHCoRQQ2AaDgeIB8ulKFqAAYmrtzg7JU7XfUDhcemI%20gZmCKyJr1iytjtVm89QDXvsmSzLomyD4UWj4EgxWQ%20pFooG4pjSrUhrHRVkdLQAIy0NOqDnVmB1z5pivnKt0ABM9bOTboMF7ba4TRRNrtcu9zF9fPaU4Vzrd-usRZ8XCAA)

Using hit n trial I found that it works if I create a type inside my method like this, but I am not sure whether its the correct way? or we should create type only in method header i.e. in <>?

```
type U = T & ActiveItemType;
const items = ref(itemsData) as Ref<U[]>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [issue comment](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2136#issuecomment-693524663) :

> When using `ref` or `reactive` with generics you need to cast to `as Ref<T>` and `as reactive<T>` if you sure that the type doesn't have any nested refs, because ref and reactive will unwrap nested refs automatically

```
   import {ref, Ref} from 'vue';
  // ... 
   const items = ref(itemsData) as Ref<T[]>;
```

Comment: then items[0].isActive not available

Comment: Try to add the property isActive `T extends { icon: string; text: string, isActive?: boolean }`

Comment: question updated... I m still not able to figure it out as ` Ref<T & ActiveItemType[]>;` is not a valid syntax